# Excel VBA - insert value with relative values

Tags: excel, vba

Would appreciate help of the experts!

I am trying to write a code where:

1. I select a cell and execute the macro  (say cell is L30)
2. VBA copies the entire row that contain the active cell (whole data (mix of formula and hard coded numbers) from row 30 is copied)
3. VBA inserts a new row beneath the copied row (so data in row 30 is moved down to row 31)
4. VBA pastes the new row (row 31) with formula and hard coded numbers from copied row (row 30)
5. In the new row's column O, VBA inserts numerical value from cell "O4" but in reverse sign (O7 has a number but it is based on a formula)
6. In the new row's column P, VBA inserts numberical value from cell "R4" but in reverse sign (R4 also has a number but it is based on a formula)
7. In P30, VBA inserts a formula where "=original P30 value - P31"

I have written the code per below.  This seems to accomplish 1,2,3,4,5, but only partial 4 and 5 because I can't seem to put negative sign for the value O7 and R4 and inserting them into the new row.

Step 6.. is something that I couldn't even get the ball rolling...

I understand that this is a lot of steps that I am asking for.
Some guidance or hints would much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.INSERT
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

Range("O4").Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4)
Range("R4").Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 5)
```

Comment: I think the best way to show what you want to do is to provide a snap shot of before and after data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim r As Range, nrow As Long, orow As Long
Set r = ActiveCell
nrow = r.Offset(1, 0).Row: orow = r.Row
r.EntireRow.Copy
r.Offset(1, 0).Insert xlDown

Range("O" & nrow) = -Range("O4") 'reverse the sign
Range("P" & nrow) = -Range("P4") 'reverse the sign
With Range("P" & orow)
    .Value = .Value - .Offset(1, 0).Value
End With
```

For Step 7, you cannot assign it as formula because that would be circular referencing.
Above code already put the result in P30 (based on your example above). HTH.

Comment: L42, thank you very much!!  The first part works precisely well!  I am studying the second part to better understand the logic behind (.value = .value - .offset(1,0).Value.  I think I would figure it out as I do some more mock up runs.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply.  I have been struggling with this for sometime, and have been doing the task manually.  Thank you! thank you!

Comment: You got it captain.  My apol for not accepting the answer earlier!  Thanks very much again.  I will also contribute as much as I can.